# Roles and responsibility as Quality Assurance Consultant

Tags: automated-testing, manual-testing, agile-testing

I have worked in incident management and code analysis, as well as testing (manual, functional, and regression).
I have a new offer as a QA consultant.
Automation testing, understanding requirements ,manual testing etc....
The way of working is scrum agile.
Can I work in this scenario with the above background?
Is it easy?

Comment: Yes you can work..Your given background is also ok with Quality Assurance Consultant. Also finally it is depends on company that how they work with QA and what are their predefined roles and responsibilities for QA. So you do not need to be worry here...your background is enough to work as QA consultant.

Comment: I don't think this is a question that has a right answer - it's going to be primarily a matter of opinion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be focused on the technical aspects of doing software QA. I would say your background is good for doing test automation and finding bugs that are results of technical obstacles. However, it takes a strong will to put up with the amount of animosity you may have to control.

I find troubling is that no one is bringing up the intense social requirements in being in Software QA. You need to be able to be understand the customer to make sure the requirements are in the customer's best interests. You need to be the customer's advocate. This could mean defending costly features. Worse of all you may be fighting a losing battle.

You will spend every day worrying about the worse case scenario. While the developers on the team are building up to some grand masterpiece you need to be the one who brings them down to earth. You may very well find a bug that sends the whole thing crumbling to the ground.

You may be viewed as overhead. Someone who is not actually producing anything. The developers are the golden children who will take us to the promise land. Software QA doesn't actually produce anything. Plus our developers have started doing TDD so there won't be any bugs.

Now if this isn't bad enough you are going to be a consultant. This doubles the pressure being placed on you. Now you will be an outsider telling people that their baby is ugly.

I am taking the worse case scenarios. The problem is that there is a large amount of people in the industry who's view of Software QA is either negative or Archaic. You may very well be lucky to have an enlightened client who sees how valuable you are.

That being said incident management and code analysis are similar professions from a social standpoint. I would say if you are happy and confident in you career so far, than the Software QA is probably not a huge jump.

Answer (score 2):

You have a very good background to apply, depending of the company maybe you have to learn something more than you know but just like everything in this life, nobody's born knowing everything. As Nike says Just do it! 
Finally want to share a very interesting article about QA role in agile teams http://www.thoughtworks.com/insights/blog/qa-role-what-it-really

Comment: That article is excellent. +1 for the reference. Could you add a summary of the main points for everyone's reference?

Answer (score 1):

> Can I work in this scenario with the above background?

First of all, **anything is possible**. It's really hard to give advice without knowing more about you and your background. Describing your background in a short post on a forum like this isn't easy.

Assuming the company who extended you the offer, knows about your current background and wants to hire you and you feel like you can adapt to the new situation then **yes** you'll probably be fine.

> Is it easy?

**Nothing is easy**. Some things may appear to be easy but if you look deep enough and long enough you'll begin to see complexity with most aspects of software. Testing is the same. As long as you are *willing to learn and hungry enough to explore* and search for ways to get better then you'll probably be ok. If you've never built automation before but you are willing to try and you put in lots of effort you will probably be successful over the long run.

There will be lots to learn. Learn about Software Testing, learn about your customers, learn about what it's like to work in an agile environment with scrum and learn as much as you can about anything you think you need to do.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You have plenty of background.  You need to focus more on what you'll be actually doing - many engineering roles in software require you to have a foundational param (with specific reqs..)

If you've never worked in Agile (Scrumming is just a part of agile BTW) then start getting familiar with it - it's really not that bad.

For me, I would personally just get an idea of how they do their tracking/UAT/Etc and go from there.  What are you worried about exactly?

Comment: In short, is going into hard core testing and QA possible or easy from my previous background..? The total experience I have is 2.2 years